# 2-part confusion with slim restful backend and twig

Tags: php, rest, twig, slim

I am building an app to better understand Restful back-ends with clients that makes calls to it. I am using slim to handle routing and service calls. I am stuck on two things though.

Part 1 - If restful APIs should not use sessions how do I keep information like authenticated and user_id available? It was my understanding storing that information in a cookie was a bad practice. Once a user authenticated normally I would use `$_SESSION['uid']`.

Part 2 - This part is more confusing to me. I am using Twig for front-end (not a cool js guy). Doing so all on the same server I use slim-view to render twig. But that means my back-end is not sending JSON it is doing everything. How is something like this separated? Is it worth while?

Comment: P1) One method is create a dynamic API key that is temporary, with this temp key you can then authenticate and authorize any request coming from the client.

P2) You need to decouple your `client` project from you `server` project. Your client should only ever receive data (e.g. `JSON`) from the `server`, your `server` should never worry about how to present the data only about sending it the client

Comment: @DarkBee Great comment I would have upped it as an answer. A couple questions. P1) Where would the key be stored? In a cookie? And then set with request from that user. Would I use that as a look up from the DB for user information? P2) Decoupling is what I thought was needed but it could still be with php correct? Essentially another server that could even run slim and slim-views I suppose?

Comment: P1) On the server side you can store the API key inside a table with some fields to keep track when the key was last used and how long the key is valid (http://imgur.com/UKWtL3X) By doing this you can invalidate API keys at the serverside / The client can store the key wherever but if you are going to use PHP then I suggest storing it in the session. P2) The client can be written in PHP. The only thing a client can't do is contact the database directly. It has to request every piece of information straight from the server

Comment: This was great help! If you made this an answer I would give you all the points and I assume this would help all the people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part one**

One method is create a dynamic API key that is temporary, with this temp key you can then authenticate and authorize any request coming from the client.

On the server side you can store this temp API key inside a table with some fields to keep track when the key was last used and how long the key is valid. By doing this you can invalidate API keys at the server side

The client can store the key wherever but if you are going to use `PHP` then I suggest storing it in the `session`

---

*sidenote:* This answer is based on an API I worked on. The field `static` in the table `api_key` is used for keys that only can be used to login an user and obtain a dynamic key that then was used for authentication and authorization.

This was due to the fact that our client was written in JS and the `static` API key was plain visible in the source code. 
So the client first had to issue a login request before obtaining a "legit" api key

---

[image: server side api storage]

**part 2**

You need to decouple your client project from you server project. Your client should only ever receive data (e.g. JSON) from the server, your server should never worry about how to present the data only about sending it the client.

The client can be written in any language and can even be hosted somewhere else. The only thing a client can't do is contact the database directly. It has to request every piece of information straight from the server